# Библиотека leakcanary. Проблемы с внедрением

Tags: android, утечка-памяти

Всем доброго дня!

Нашел интересный инструмент для отслеживания ошибок типа `ООМ` - [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). Есть пару статей на русском языке [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/leakcanary.php) и [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/257633/).
Проблема в том, что у меня не получается внедрить в свой проект(специально создал проект).

код активити, которое запускается из главного активити

```
public class ac2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Cat schrodingerCat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ssss);

    Box box = new Box();
    schrodingerCat = new Cat();
    box.hiddenCat = schrodingerCat;
    Docker.container = box;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = ExampleApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
    refWatcher.watch(this);
    refWatcher.watch(schrodingerCat);
}
```

код класса, наследующего application

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

private RefWatcher refWatcher;

public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
    ExampleApplication application = (ExampleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    return application.refWatcher;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
}}
```

и три класса, которые помогают создавать `ООМ`

```
public class Cat {
}
public class Box {
    Cat hiddenCat;
}
public class Docker {
    static Box container;
}
```

приложение падает, когда я закрываю ас2 активити(возвращаюсь в главному).
видимо я что-то не понимаю, кто сталкивался с проблемой прошу помочь.
делаю как говорят [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/debug/leakcanary.php)

ошибка - приведение типов. падает в строке

```
ExampleApplication application = (ExampleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
```

E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: canaryleak.ac2 cannot be cast to canaryleak.ExampleApplication

E/AndroidRuntime: at canaryleak.ExampleApplication.getRefWatcher(ExampleApplication.java:17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не прописали свой `Application` в манифесте. Допишите в раздел `application` параметр `name` с именем вашего `Application`

```
<application
        ...
        android:name=".ExampleApplication ">

        ...

</application>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Детская ошибка(